# Using onBlur on a TextField can cause OOM

Tags: material-ui, textfield, onblur

I am seeing Chrome crash with just before OOM and it is related to the onBlur of a TextField, even if it's just a simple console.log of the event, any ideas / pointers? This is using 3.9.1.

```
onBlur={evt => { console.log(evt); }}
```

[image: Browser OOM crash]

Comment: Can you provide more code / context?

Comment: Just found out it seems to be related to using the Sentry react integration. If I leave out Sentry from the mix, all is fine.

Answer (score 1):

My specific issue was caused by @sentry/browser

Upgrading from 4.5.4 to 4.6.4 fixed it